# Why does my dash app structure calculates the data twice?

Tags: python, module, plotly-dash

I have a dash apllication and the following 4 Modules. app needs to be imported from dashboard.py and tab_OIA.py as both modules work with app. This is also the way recommended by the plotly dash website:

- app.py:

  ```
  import dash
  app = dash.Dash(__name__,suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
  ```
- dashboard.py:

  ```
  from app import app 
  from tab_OIA import tab_OIA_layout
      .
      .
      .
  if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=True)
  ```
- tab_OIA.py:

  ```
  from app import app 
  import data

  tab_OIA_layout = html.Div(.....)

  @app.callback()
  def function():
     return ..
  ```
- data.py:

  ```
  import pandas 
  *calculate stuff*
  print("Everything calculated")
  ```

When I run dashboard.py in cmd it shows the following and "Everything calculated" appears twice:

```
C:\Users\.spyder-py3>python dashboard.py
Everything calculated
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 111-463-400
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
Everything calculated
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 101-604-170
```

Calculating the data twice takes a lot of time. Why does that happen? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I think the debug mode makes your application run twice. Topic discussed in this link: https://community.plotly.com/t/code-in-if---name-----main---runs-twice/5868

Answer (score -1):

You import `app.py` twice. To fix this, try removing `from app import app` from `dashboard.py`.

```py
#from app import app 
from tab_OIA import *
    .
    .
    .
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run_server(debug=True, threaded=True)
```

Comment: I need to import app so I can run the app from the module dashboard.py. Otherwise I get an error, this is also the recommended way from the official dash website

Comment: Then you will need to remove it from tab_OIA.py then as you are importing it twice. You may find it easier to combine two file. Also, the way I have changed it above just imports app from tab_OIA so it should still work. Theoretically...

Comment: Well app needs to be imported here as well, as tab_OIA also defines some @app.callback functions. Sorry I edited my question now. App needs to be imported from both modules (and this is also the recommended way from the website)

Comment: Do you have the link to the specific documentation on the website? This could help to provide more information

Comment: Sure, it's here: https://dash.plotly.com/urls under the section "Structuring a Mulit-Page App". My dashboard.py equals their index.py

Comment: Hmm, it seems like their code has the same problem. That is very odd to see. My only suggestion is to try my solution or choose a different app structure. Sorry I can't be of more help